Подключение .dll сборки OpenCV with CUDA
Собрал OpenCV with CUDA под Java при помощи CMake. В Project Structure в IntelliJ добавил JAR и местоположение core library.


В классе Main выполняю загрузку библиотеки в static-блоке:
public class Main {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}

При запуске приложения возникает следующая ошибка:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\opencv_4_9_with_cuda_build\lib\Release\opencv_java490.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:287)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2427)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1993)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:25)

При этом opencv_java490.dll находится по пути D:\opencv_4_9_with_cuda_build\lib\Release\opencv_java490.dll, а все остальные файлы по пути D:\opencv_4_9_with_cuda_build\bin\Release.
Пробовал указать пути к .dll в параметре JVM java.library.path - не помогло.

См. Eng SO: "How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project"
